# Accessing iOS filesystem the way iPhone does

Tags: ios, filesystems

I am trying to connect to my iPhone via `iTunesMobileDevice.dll` and other [libraries](https://archive.codeplex.com/?p=mobiledevice) provided by iTunes. So far I am able to reach the file system and copy images from iPhone. However images are stored in directories titled `101APPLE` to `109APPLE` and the filesystem looks something like this:

```
...
/PhotoStreamsData/.MISC
/PhotoStreamsData/.MISC/Incoming
/DCIM
/DCIM/101APPLE
...
/DCIM/.MISC
/DCIM/.MISC/Timelapse
/DCIM/.MISC/Incoming
...
/PhotoData/Metadata
/PhotoData/Metadata/DCIM
/PhotoData/Metadata/DCIM/109APPLE
/PhotoData/Metadata/DCIM/108APPLE
/PhotoData/Metadata/DCIM/107APPLE
/PhotoData/Metadata/DCIM/106APPLE
/PhotoData/AlbumsMetadata
...
```

Now I need to extract the Album data as well and rearrange images in the related albums which I have made on my iPhone.

My question is that where the album data (and other metadata about images like time or ...) is stored? and how is it possible to extract them?

I have asked this question on the **AskDiffernet Community** but no answers there, So I thought maybe it concerns developers more than Apple users.

Comment: This doesn't appear to be a programming question. This is not the correct place for such a question.

Comment: @rmaddy where should I put it? can you help?

Comment: Ask Different was the correct place if your question is about iOS. If you are actually doing some programming, then this is the correct place but you need to edit your question and show what programming you are doing.